# SSIS , counting files in a folder using script task, looping the task untill number of files reaches 25

Tags: ssis-2012, msbi

Need to develop a package which should read number of files from ftp/folder. If the count is less than 25 , keep looping, Go to the next task once the count reaches 25.

What i tried is:

I used a script task, created few variable and variable have file count(Successfully). I used expression in precedence constraint for checking if the number of files in a particular folder is 25. if not it wont go to another task. What i cant do is keep the script task looping until the file count becomes 25. I tried using for each loop but couldn't get trough. please suggest.

Please have a look at this.  i have 2 script tasks. first one counts and display the number of files in a folder. here is the script for that.

```
enter code here


public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

            String FolderPath = 
Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string Prefix = 
Dts.Variables["User::prefix"].Value.ToString();
            Int32 FileCnt = 0;
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(Prefix + "*");
            //Declare and initilize variables            
            //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                FileCnt += 1;
                MessageBox.Show(file.Name);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(FileCnt.ToString());
            Dts.Variables["User::FileCnt"].Value = 
Convert.ToInt32(FileCnt);
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of 
this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
}
```

then i edited the precedence constraint and wrote and expression @FileCnt == 25, which means next script task will only be executed when the number of files in the folder is 25. what i want now is that the first script task should be running in a loop until the folder gets 25 file. i think we need to use foreachloop container here. did you get what im looking for now??

Comment: Could you add sample that would demonstrate what you tried so far?

Comment: @rudolf_franek , please check the question again. i have modified it for better understanding. i dont know if i can put screenshot here.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest??